# repeat angular function python

Tags: python, function

```
  def ang(theta1,theta2,x1,x2,r,dens):
        theta = []
        r1 = []
        ds = []

       #note x1,x2 is input data

       theta = np.arctan2(x1,x2)
       ang_deg = (theta*180)/(np.pi)

       for i in range(len(ang_deg)):
            if theta1 <= ang_deg[i]<= theta2:
                r1.append(r[i])
                ds.append(dens[i])

       return
```

This function is working OK but I would like to know how could I code it such that instead of say calculating for theta1 = 0 and theta2 =10 degrees only ,how can I optimize it such that can do it do it several times like from 0,10, then 10,20 then 20,30 degrees giving r1 and ds for each of this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always just create a different function:

```
def ang_multiple(theta1s, theta2s, x1, x2, r, dens):
   results = []
   for i, theta1 in enumerate(theta1s):
       results.append(ang(theta1, theta2s[i], x1, x2, r dens))
   return results
```